# Printing minimum answer as list?

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate min1([4,2,3,5],L). I want it to return the minimum number for each time the list is sent back as a tail. Example:

```
List       Head|Tail    Tail     L
[4,2,3,5]  [4,2,3,5]    [2,3,5]  2
[2,3,5]    [2,3,5]      [3,5]    2
[3,5]      [3,5]        [5]      3
[5]        [5]          []       5
```

My code:

```
min([X],[X]).
min([H|T],Min):-
    min(T,TMin),
    H=<TMin,
    Min is H.
min([H|T],Min):-
    min(T,TMin),
    H>TMin,
    Min is TMin.

min1([],[]).
min1([H|T],L):-
  min([H|T],R),
    write(R),
    min1(T,R).
```

The problem that I am facing **is with L**. It does not print anything. When I use **write(R)**, it's showing me the right result but I am unable to print it as a List in L. What should I correct?

```
?-min1([4,2,3,5],L).
223[5]
L = []
```

By removing write(R):

```
?-min1([4,2,3,5],L).
false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your problems is trying to understand your program using I/O. This is often not a very useful thing to do in Prolog. If you are interested in the suffixes of the list, even just for debugging, expose those suffixes as an argument of the predicate. This is much clearer than trying to print intermediate results. Because Prolog backtracks, it can be hard to understand what an intermediate result means, at what point it exists, and whether you can actually use it before backtracking makes it disappear.

Your other problem is trying to do too much at once. Take things step by step. Prolog is a language that is well suited for decomposing problems into tiny bits. It also often *forces* you to decompose a problem into tiny bits.

So, first: Enumerating a list's suffixes (including the list itself as a trivial suffix).

```
list_suffix(List, List).
list_suffix([_ | Suffix], SuffixOfSuffix) :-
    list_suffix(Suffix, SuffixOfSuffix).

?- list_suffix([4, 2, 3, 5], Suffix).
Suffix = [4, 2, 3, 5] ;
Suffix = [2, 3, 5] ;
Suffix = [3, 5] ;
Suffix = [5] ;
Suffix = [].
```

Then, **separately**, computing the minimum of a list. Your implementation is almost OK for this, the first clause needed to unwrap `[X]` (though it could be more efficient by using an accumulator):

```
list_minimum([X], X).
list_minimum([H | T], Min):-
    list_minimum(T, TMin),
    H =< TMin,
    Min is H.
list_minimum([H | T], Min):-
    list_minimum(T, TMin),
    H > TMin,
    Min is TMin.

?- list_minimum([4, 2, 3, 5], Minimum).
Minimum = 2 ;
false.
```

Now, and **only now**, we are in a position to tackle the combined problem:

```
?- list_suffix([4, 2, 3, 5], Suffix), list_minimum(Suffix, Minimum).
Suffix = [4, 2, 3, 5],
Minimum = 2 ;
Suffix = [2, 3, 5],
Minimum = 2 ;
Suffix = [3, 5],
Minimum = 3 ;
Suffix = [5],
Minimum = 5 ;
false.
```

You can pack this up in a predicate definition:

```
list_suffix_suffixminimum(List, Suffix, SuffixMinimum) :-
    list_suffix(List, Suffix),
    list_minimum(Suffix, SuffixMinimum).

?- list_suffix_suffixminimum([4, 2, 3, 5], Suffix, SuffixMinimum).
Suffix = [4, 2, 3, 5],
SuffixMinimum = 2 ;
Suffix = [2, 3, 5],
SuffixMinimum = 2 ;
Suffix = [3, 5],
SuffixMinimum = 3 ;
Suffix = [5],
SuffixMinimum = 5 ;
false.
```

Maybe even without exposing the suffix:

```
list_suffixminimum(List, SuffixMinimum) :-
    list_suffix(List, Suffix),
    list_minimum(Suffix, SuffixMinimum).

?- list_suffixminimum([4, 2, 3, 5], SuffixMinimum).
SuffixMinimum = 2 ;
SuffixMinimum = 2 ;
SuffixMinimum = 3 ;
SuffixMinimum = 5 ;
false.
```

Now, and **only now** that the problem has been solved, you can add I/O if you feel like it. Although at this point, why would you?

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. Can you explain to me one small thing list_suffix(List, List). why List,List in the base case?

Comment: Because from your examples it looked like you wanted the sequence 2, 2, 3, 5. You only get 2 twice if you also treat the list itself as its suffix, so once you compute the minimum of `[4, 2, 3, 5]` to get 2, then the minimum of `[2, 3, 5]` to get 2 as well.